# Sankey plot in plotly throws arrowlen error

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to replicate the example here: https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/

Specifically, I want to use the last example with the arrows. However, I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.sankey.Link: 'arrowlen'
```

I am not sure why as I am using plotly version 5.15.0:

```
!pip install plotly==5.15.0
!pip install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.5"
```

The exact code in my jupyter notebook is as follows:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Sankey(
    arrangement='snap',
    node=dict(
        label=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
        x=[0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5],
        y=[0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3],
        pad=10  
    ),
    link=dict(
        arrowlen=15,
        source=[0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5],
        target=[5, 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3],
        value=[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
        
    )
))

fig.show()
```

Comment: I  am getting the graph on my colab, what is your python version?

Comment: @GodIsOne: Python 3.8.5